# how to pass configuration file to scala jar file

Tags: scala, configuration, typesafe

I am using the [typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) library in my code and then I generate a jar file. The application works fine when I embed the reference.conf file inside the jar. But is it possible to provide the config file as a parameter to the jar ? for example

```
java -DmyconfigFile=/dir/dir/reference.conf -jar myjar package.class.myobject.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is. See this thread on using an external akka config [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/akka-user/np6jxjzv3n8/piqP87xyCY4J).

```
java -Dconfig.file=/dir/dir/reference.conf -jar myjar package.class.myobject.
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to override the reference.conf file that already exists in the jar file?

Comment: You might want to read that thread I linked to some more and links in the thread. I'm not sure that you're supposed to replace `reference.conf`, just override it with other settings. Also, you can pass `-Dconfig.trace=loads` to trace what's being loaded and where.