# Superseding scala conf file as JVM argument?

Tags: scala, configuration, jvm

I have an `application.conf` file that is read by my program (via `com.typesafe.config`) at each run. I would now like to keep only standard settings in that file, and be able to specify a superseding conf file `thisrun.conf` for each run (i.e. the app should use configs from `thisrun.conf` and fall back on `application.conf` for any missing configs).

Can this be done by simply passing the `thisrun.conf` file as a parameter to the JVM, or do I have to pass it as an argument to my app? [**A previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623728/how-to-pass-configuration-file-to-scala-jar-file) shows how to pass a config file using `-Dconfig.file`, but this seems to *bypass* `application.conf`, rather than supersede it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way of superseding `application.conf` with `thisrun.conf` using the `-Dconfig.file` argument. Simply put as the first line in `thisrun.conf`:

```
include "application.conf"
```

This way the behavior will be exactly as asked in the question.

I would still be interested if there are other ways of doing the same, that do not require an explicit include of `application.conf`.